# Cannot read property 'ensureClientConfigured' of null in Firebase Firestore - ReactJS

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am using redux and redux-saga in my react app and I have this saga which runs for user registration.

```
function* registerWithPassword(user: UserInput) {
  try {
    const userData: firebase.auth.UserCredential = yield call(
      registerUser,
      user.email,
      user.password
    );
    if (userData === null || userData.user === null) {
      yield put(
        authFailureAction.failure({
          register: 'Unable to register user',
        })
      );
    } else {
      const firestore = firebase.firestore();
      const userDoc: firestore.DocumentReference = yield call(firestore.doc, `${USERS}/${userData.user.uid}`);
      yield call(
        userDoc.set,
        { labels: [], pinnedNotes: [], name: user.name },
        { merge: true }
      );
      yield call(console.log, 'Updated doc')
      yield put(firebaseUserAction.success(userData));
    }
  } catch (e) {
    yield put(
      authFailureAction.failure({
        register: e.message || 'Unable to register user',
      })
    );
  }
}
```

These actions are just utils to construct an action to dispatch to redux.

I'm first registering the user, and then adding some data in firestore.

I keep getting this error when firestore tries to write data to firebase
`Cannot read property 'ensureClientConfigured' of null firebase`.

I tried searching this in Google and to my surprise, no one has ever gotte n this error.

Here is my firebase config file

```
import * as firebase from 'firebase';
import 'firebase/firestore';

const config = {
  apiKey: process.env.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_API_KEY,
  authDomain: process.env.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_AUTH_DOMAIN,
  databaseURL: process.env.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_DATABASE_URL,
  projectId: process.env.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_PROJECT_ID,
  storageBucket: process.env.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_STORAGE_BUCKET,
  messagingSenderId: process.env.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_MESSAGING_SENDER_ID,
};

if (firebase.apps.length === 0) {
  firebase.initializeApp(config);
}

export default firebase;
```

Answer (score 0):

my hypothesis that `Cannot read property 'ensureClientConfigured' of null firebase` occured because the app cannot recognize the initialization of your firebase.

I guess, you should create a variable in your firebase config file:

```
export const firestore = firebase.firestore()
```

then import this variable in to the file of your function. and modify your function file according to the new updates.

please, let me know if this helps.

Comment: Yeah. I went through the source code and this seemed like the only reason firebase couldn't work. But then I tried this and it still wouldn't fix anything. I also have Firebase Auth in my app. If firebase instance for firestore is null, it should be for Auth too, but Auth works perfectly.

Comment: Can you please provide me with full version of file where your redux-saga function including all imports?. becasue I cannot give you a full answer with this much of information